# select multiple items in select option without using 'ctrl' key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there a way I could select multiple items in multiple select dropdown without using 'ctrl'? below is my snippet which so far I tried and unfortunately not working. Any help, ideas, clues, suggestions, recommendations please?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#options option").click(function(){
    $(this).prop("selected",true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="options" class="form-control" multiple>
  <option value="1">option one</option>
  <option value="2">option two</option>
  <option value="3">option three</option>
  <option value="4">option four</option>
  <option value="5">option five</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can just click the first value and drag down, if they're sequential, but more practically you could use any number of select plugins

Answer (score 2):

You could go for a jQuery plugin solution. [DEMO JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/knbdm5hu/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $('select').multipleSelect();
});
```

You can find the 'multiple select' project at [GitHub](https://github.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select)